# Custom UITableViewCell Not updating on Search

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm using a uitableviewcontroller with a uiSearchBar. In the searchBarSearchButtonClicked method I get data and populate it in the uitableviewcontroller:

```
 - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    NSDictionary *data = [self getData];

    [self.tableData removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableData addObjectsFromArray:[data objectForKey:@"myKey"]];
    [self.view reloadData];
 }
```

The problems is that I am using a custom uitableviewcell.  When I click the search button new rows are returned, but the rows retrieved when the previous search was ran still remain.

For example if my initial search returned 1 result row and I do an additional search this time returning 3 rows, the first row will be from the first search and the subsequent two rows will be from the second search.

I reload the data in the view so I'm not sure why the cells are persisting.  Here is my cellforrowatindexpath method where I create the cells:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"SearchResult";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

NSDictionary *data = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
             reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];



myLabelDetail = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(152.0, 32.0, 60.0, 5.0)];
myLabelDetail.tag = INSTRUMENT_ID_LABEL_TAG;
myLabelDetail.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
myLabelDetail.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
myLabelDetail.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
myLabelDetail.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
myLabelDetail.text = [data objectForKey:@"title"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:myLabelDetail];
[myLabelDetail release];



cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Title Text";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"My Label: ";


cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}else{
    myLabelDetail = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:DETAIL_LABEL_TAG];
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
 }else{
      myLabelDetail = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:DETAIL_LABEL_TAG];
      // i needed to add this to update when cell is already initialized
      myLabelDetail = [data objectForKey:@"title"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in using the data source. I guess **tableData** is the array you use for providing data to the tableview as it is flushed and loaded with new objects every time the  **- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar** method is called. But **tableData** is not used anywhere inside **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method. Providing data to tableView from **tableData** array may solve your problem.

Comment: tabledata is right above the if statement. Is that what you meant?  I moved it outside the if statement but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are just assigning a particular object of **tableData** to **data** with this statement `NSDictionary *data = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` But after that, **data** is used no where.

Comment: I have added how I intended to use data in the detailtext label for the cell. This still has the same result.

Comment: Could you post your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method here?